# Javascript not loading on site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, countdowntimer

for some reason my code etc. is working locally, but when i upload it the javascript simply isn't working. It's almost like it's a blank page with only some styling.

The site is at the following URL:
http://www.countdown2zodiac.com/

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I saw many 'NOT FOUND' errors in you website. Check the configuration of your webserver

Comment: you have not provided correct path for js file

Answer (score 1):

Did you check you have the files in the correct directory? I tried to access to your jquery file and server says file doesn't exist.

Comment: i'll double check, one second!

Comment: yep, should be fine. I basically just copied everything over as it was from my computer to the site via ftp

Answer (score 0):

if you check the console, it'll show you that it can't find the files

```
GET http://www.countdown2zodiac.com/js/counter.js 404 (Not Found) http://www.countdown2zodiac.com/:24
GET http://www.countdown2zodiac.com/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js 404 (Not Found)
```

so either you have uploaded it in a wrong directory or the server can't access the files so you probably should check the access rights.

Comment: they're definitely in the right place.. how would i check access rights?

Comment: it depends on how you actually upload the files, if you use an ftp application such as flashFXP you just right click the file and check the permissions, and change them to something like read and write.
If you can use ssh, connect to the server and use "ls -l" to see if the files are readable and check the owner, the owner should be the "www-data" user, if the files are owned by root, you won't be able to read/access those files using the www user

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4650892/Capture.JPG

there's a screen cap of the ftp client. I've just gone through and given full permissions (except for public write). 
Public Execute is unchecked and when i check it it somehow unchecks again... Would that be the problem?

Comment: http://www.countdown2zodiac.com/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js
this file either doesn't exist or is not accessible.
so i guess, you are right, if you can't change the permission of the file you probably don't have the rights to do so.
either you try to upload it again or you contact a server administrator if you don't have root access and you are not able to just change the permissions

Comment: and i think, your thinking is right :)
but i can't help you with that one since i have no information what so ever to actually figure out the problem, i am sorry

Comment: Actually, i've disconnected and reconnected to the server and that message seems to have stopped appearing...

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4650892/Capture3.JPG
There's a screen cap proving that every file has absolutely full permissions.
I also changed the site around a bit so nothing is in folders any more, it's all in the root directory. Still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Please fix the following erorrs. They are all 404, not found:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

there is problem with two of your js function

```
http://www.countdown2zodiac.com/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"
http://www.countdown2zodiac.com/js/counter.js"
```

the browser is somehow unable to find it